singular ideal of matrix rings
Let $R$ be a ring with identity. An element $x\in R$ is said to be right singular if $xI=0$ for some essential right ideal $I$ of $R$. The set of all right singular elements of $R$  is denoted by $Z_r(R)$ or $Z(R_R)$. It forms an ideal of $R$ and called as right singular ideal of $R$.
Question: Let $R$ be a ring with identity and $n$ be a positive integer. Is $Z_r(M_n(R))=M_n(Z_r(R))$?
My finding: attempt-1: Since we know that each ideal of the matrix ring $M_n(R)$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$, hence the right singular ideal $Z_r(M_n(R))$ is of the form $M_n(I)$ for some ideal $I$ of $R$. Now we have need to prove that $I=Z_r(R)$, if possible.
my attempt-2: Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in M_n(Z_r(R))$. Then $a_{ij}\in Z_r(R)$. So there exists an essential right ideal $I_{ij}$ of $R$ such that $a_{ij}I_{ij}=0$. If we take $I=\cap I_{ij} $, then $I$ is an essential right ideal of $R$ such that $a_{ij}I=0$ for all $i,j$. Hence if we take $J=M_n(I)$, then $J$ is an essential right ideal of $M_n(R)$ such that $AJ=0$. So $A\in Z_r(M_n(R))$. Thus $M_n(Z_r(R))\subseteq Z_r(M_n(R))$.

What you've found so far is true but not directly helpful.  You're going to have to go deeper and consider how annihilators in $M_n(R)$ relate to those in $R$.

Now I have corrected my question.
